# How can I like a Fanpage with the Facebook Graph API

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-actionscript-api

it is possible to lika a FanPage with the actionscript3 Facebook Api or the Graph API?

I used follow methode:

```
Facebook.api(Page_ID + "/likes/", getLikeHandler, URLRequestMethod.POST);
```

But I get follow Exception

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

Do you have an solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible via any of the public Facebook APIs. You can only publish 'likes' for Open Graph objects.